# How were all of Wolverine's bones covered with Adamantium?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, x-men-origins-wolverine

OK, so in the *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* movie, we see clearly for the first time how his bones became covered with Adamantium but it raises another question... How were *all* of his bones covered with Adamantium?

If you watch the scene you will see that there are only a few places on the major bones like his skull where there are marks for the placement of the needles.

But there is not a mark for every bone in his body. So, how did the Adamantium travel to cover every bone? Should it not have just covered those that were closest to the needles?

Comment: Through the magic of Hollywood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the way in which the clip you provide above shows the spread of the red along the bones, it looks like something in the process causes the Adamantium to spread along the surface of the bone. Thus, they don't need to target every bone individually, but rather, they inject it at several major points and then it spreads.

As per [your other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/132607/how-were-wolverines-joints-not-frozen-when-he-was-injected-with-the-adamantium), it raises the question of how exactly it jumps joint gaps without fusing the bones together, but that could be something as simple as that the process they're using only fuses as a sheet along the surface of bone.

Comment: It might be *in* his bones rather than on? But that would be odd as well because then how does it neatly get into every finger bone?

Comment: The comic books have been ambiguous about whether the adamantium is plated on the surface of the bones, or is inside the bones. Both have been depicted as the truth. Given Wolverine's later usage of the equipment to inject adamantium into Lady Deathstroke, it looks like the intent was for injection, but the way in which we see it move in the imagery suggests plating.

Comment: Well in truth it isn't that important...