# How were Wolverines joints not frozen when he was injected with the Adamantium?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, x-men-origins-wolverine

So if we think about it they just poured/injected liquid Adamantium over Wolverines bones... but should it not have pooled in between his joints and locked them like glue does if you put it on something movable? Like a lego doll.

Comment: I suspect it was something closer to a dip coating

Comment: I always thought they were *injecting* adamantium **in** his bones, and imbueing them... in this case the joints wouldn't be touched.

Comment: arguable dupe: [How can Wolverine stand with so much Adamantium?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/16341/5184). Thaddeus' answer touches on this.

Comment: “So if we think about it they just poured/injected liquid Adamantium over Wolverines bones” — only if we think about things differently from [how they](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7989/440) [actually happened](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14512/440).